# check True in .format python discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, string.format

```
await Bot.send_message(message.channel, "**{}**, you have:\n{}".format(message.author.name, author_dragon > 0))
```

In the second `{}` only appears `True`, I would like him to show an emoji like , what should I do?
Give me full answers, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just send the unicode character. It will be automatically converted to an emoji

```
await Bot.send_message(message.channel, "**{}**, you have:\n".format(message.author.name))
```